# match the following pattern

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a lot of (p. #) like (p. 13) (p. 234) in a string and I want to remove them. I used the following pattern to match but it doesn't work

```
preg_replace('/\(p\.*\)/','',$string);

( to escape (
p is p
\. to escape .
```

I need some help here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regular expression you're looking for:

```
\(p\.\s+\d+\)
```

Or, in your code:

```
preg_replace('/\(p\.\s+\d+\)/', '', $string);
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://regex101.com/r/uA9tV7/2).

Comment: Thank you so much for the fiddle!. I found out the space in html is &nbsp; so I changed the pattern to \(p\.&nbsp;+\d+\). Everything is all set.

Answer (score 1):

You have nothing in your regexp to match the page number. You're just matching something like `(p.......)`.

```
preg_replace('/\(p\.\s*\d+\s*\)/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

The * means to match 0 or more of the preceding item, so it would be working on the . character in your example.  Perhaps you might need something like:

```
preg_replace('/\(p\. ?[0-9]+\)/','',$string);
```

This matches:

- (p.
- Then a space, which the ? makes optional
- Then one or more digits 0-9, due to the +
- Then )

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First at all `preg_replace` is a function, not a procedure, if you want to see any changes, you need to write:

```
$str = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

In your pattern you wrote `\.*` that means *a literal . zero or more times*, I assume that is not what you want. I assume you wanted to write `\..*` *a literal . and zero or more characters*. But this doesn't work too for two reasons: this doesn't check if characters are digits, and since the `*` quantifier is greedy, `.*` will match the all the characters until the end of the line and will backtrack until the last parenthesis.

The good way is probably Barmar pattern that checks there is at least a digit (using the `+` quantifier) or the same more constraignant (without a variable number of spaces):

```
/\(p\. \d+\)/
```